# How to fix the error InterpolatingPolynomial::ipdup: The abscissas are not distinct

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation

I'm trying to plot the function `Abs[InterpolatingPolynomial[..] - f[x]]` where f is a function. I receive the error:

> InterpolatingPolynomial::ipdup: The abscissas are not distinct.

This is my actual code:

```
f[c_] := E^(4*c);
Do[x[k] = If[k < 4, 0, 1], {k, 0, 4}];

Plot[Abs[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{x[0], f[x[0]]}, {x[1], 
      f[x[1]]}, {x[2], f[x[2]]}, {x[3], f[x[3]]}, {x[4], 
      f[x[4]]}}, w] - f[w]], {w, 0, 5}]
```

Why am I receiving the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't make them the same?  (The abscissas are the values of `x[k]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 But I need them like that. `x0 = x1 = x2 = x3 = 0, x4 = 1`

Comment: But a function can have only one value at an abscissa.  Can you say a little more about what you're trying to do?  Whatever it is, you can't model it with a function, unless you omit `x1`, `x2`, `x3` from the code.  Since the values `f[x1]` etc. are the same as `f[x0]`, omitting them would be no problem (in the model represented by your code).

Comment: Have you clicked the `>>` behind the error message? Did it help in any way?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes, it confirms what Michael is saying: there shouldn't be same first elements in the pairs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'll try to explain. I've written my own interpolating function and am trying to check if it and the built in one return the same values. Can you give me an example of the function call, after omitting the variables?

Comment: You can strip the redundant points with `Union` : `InterpolatingPolynomial[Union@{{..`. (You realize you only have two distinct points of course )

Comment: Omitting the x1, x2, x3 or using `Union` does do job. Thanks! If someone sums up the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summed up and cleaned:

```
f[c_] := E^(4*c);
x[_] = 0;
x[4] = 1;
t = Union@Table[{x[i], f[x[i]]}, {i, 0, 4}];
Plot[Abs[InterpolatingPolynomial[t, w] - f[w]], {w, 0, 5}]
```